# Python equivalent of full webpage download

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to create a basic scraper that will scrape Username and Song Title from a search on Soundcloud. By inspecting the element I needed (using Chrome), I found I needed to find the string associated with every tag 'span' with title="soundTitle__usernameText".  Using `BeautifulSoup`, `urllib2`, and `lxml`, I have the following code for a search 'robert delong':

```
from lxml import html
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from urllib2 import urlopen
import requests

def search_results(url):
    html = urlopen(url).read() 
    # html = requests.get(url)      I've tried this also
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "lxml")
    usernames = [span.string for span in soup.find_all("span", "soundTitle__usernameText")]
    return usernames

print search_results('http://soundcloud.com/search?q=robert%20delong')
```

This returns an empty list. However, when I save the complete webpage on Chrome by selecting File>Save>Format-Webpage, Complete, and use that associated HTML file instead of the file obtained with `urlopen`, the code then prints

> [u'Two Door Cinema Club', u'whatever-28', u'AWOLNATION', u'Two Door Cinema Club', u'Sean Glass', u'Capital Cities', u'Robert DeLong', u'RAC', u'JR JR']

which is the ideal outcome. To me, it appears that `urlopen` uses somewhat truncated HTML code to conduct its search, which is why it returns an empty list.

Any thoughts on how I may be able to access the same HTML obtained by manually saving the webpage, but using Python/Terminal? Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You guessed right. Downloaded HTML does not contain all the data. Javascript is used to request information in JSON format which is then inserted into the document.

By looking at the request Chrome made (ctrl+shift+i, "Network"), I see that it requested `https://api-v2.soundcloud.com/search?q=robert%20delong`. I believe the response to that has the information you need.

Actually, this is good for you. Reading JSON should me much more straight-forward than parsing HTML ;)

Comment: Awesome! Updated code now allows for the obtaining of all information that I need! Just imported the `json` module and included `r = requests.get(url).json()` and `return json.dumps(r, sort_keys=True, indent=4, separators=(',', ': '))` in the `search_results` function (the second part was to make the output pretty.

Answer (score 2):

This is the code that you can use to download the html of the webpage using terminal and its related links and images:
`wget -p --convert-links http://www.website.com/directory/webpage.html`